# CreateJS CDN link that uses https? For use in DoubleClick and other Ad networks

Tags: https, cdn, createjs

I like that Flash CC 2015 Canvas uses CreateJS, however it's not working in doubleclick as the CDN serving the .js files is being served http and doubleclick needs it to be served as https.

Is create JS aware of this and do they have updated CDN links that we can use when uploading html5 creative to doubleclick, sizemek or other ad networks?

> Asset is not SSL-compliant.  The following resources are
>   non-compliant:  http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js 
>   http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js

Comment: Scratch that question, looks like the https of the same name have the files as well. Just add the s to https to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security trick is to make all the `http://` calls into `https://`. Just add the **s**.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try removing the scheme **http**? All should be left is `//code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js`. I got a similar complaint.

Answer (score 1):

Doubleclick now hosts CreateJS on their own CDN: https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6307288

Answer (score 0):

Due to the irruption of RTB and Big Ad inventories, non secure protocol url are not allowed.

So, as said you could do both: // or http://

Also, for AdServers, many of them do not accept Folder structure. CreateJS creates an "image" folder for the assets, It is better if you have every asset at root level.

Comment: Just for reference, it is Flash Pro's export that creates the images folder (and others).